# Find MAC address through direct ethernet connection

Tags: networking, mac-address, dhcp, arp

I want to find the MAC address of a device. Example: Plug a network cable from my linux mashine to the target device, send some command, receive MAC.

The best solution I have now is to connect a router to the device, wait for it to give out a dhcp lease, connect to the router via ssh and read out the lease table.

I understand that dhcp servers wait for a request from the device and then give out a lease but I would like to actively send some request to the device and get the MAC from the answer directly.

The biggest problem seems to be that without running a dhcp server I can't communicate with the device. Can this be done through a lower layer? Maybe an ARP request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by listening for packets from the target mashine and extracting the mac address from the first packet we get.

Thanks for all the answers though!

Answer (score 0):

Ping the other device first and the run the command

```
arp -a
```

You can see the MAC address of the device you just pinged.

Comment: And what address does he ping?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the MAC address of a device the only way to communicate with it is via some sort of broadcast. This implies that there is some software active on the host listening for such a broadcast that will reply. This is how hosts (using ARP) resolve MAC addresses on the local network from an IP address. ARP won't work for you unless you know the IP address.

If you just have a device with no protocol support you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, there is wireshark (or the CLI version tshark):

```
sudo apt-get install tshark
sudo tshark -i eth0
```

You will see every packet your laptop or the attached device is sending over that ethernet interface.  Assuming the device is powered on, you will probably see the MAC address you are looking for somewhere in all of the low level network protocol spew. If you aren't getting much spew, try re-plugging the ethernet cable.  (Sorry; I came here looking for a better answer myself)